# Como escrever uma string em um fluxo usando arquivos físicos?

Tags: c

Ao inserir em um arquivo de texto os caracteres de uma `string` em C, os espaços em branco são ignorados. Como devo fazer para que frases longas dentro de uma string tenham as palavras separadas?

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    int op = 10, k;
    char str[100], c, arquivo[20];
    FILE *fluxo;
    do{
        printf("Digite:\n1- Criar arquivo\n2- Inserir no arquivo\n3- Ler arquivo\n4- Fechar fluxo\n5- Remover arquivo");
        scanf("%d",&op);
        switch(op){
            case 1:
                printf("\nDigite o nome do arquivo: \n");
                scanf("%s",arquivo);
                fluxo = fopen(arquivo,"w");
                if(!fluxo)
                    printf("\n***Erro ao abrir/criar arquivo!***\n");
            break;
            case 2:
                printf("\nDigite o texto a ser gravado:\n");    
                scanf("%s",str);
                for (k=0;str[k];k++){
                    c = str[k];
                    putc(c, fluxo);
                }
                    //fprintf(fluxo, "%s",str);             
            break;
            case 3:
                fclose(fluxo);
                fluxo = fopen(arquivo, "r");
                while(!feof(fluxo)){
                    fscanf(fluxo,"%c", &c);
                    printf("%c",c);
                }
            break;
            case 4:
                fclose(fluxo);
            break;
            case 5:
                remove(arquivo);
            break;
        }
    }while(op!=0);
    fclose(fluxo);

}
```

Comment: Acho que o seu problema não está na hora de escrever o arquivo, mas sim na hora de ler. `scanf` lê uma `string` até o primeiro espaço em branco.

Comment: Não é o scanf, pois o arquivo quando eu abro o arquivo destino, ele também está sem espaços, com todas as palavras concatenadas.

Comment: Perceba que você está dando `fscanf`em *loop*. A cada `fscanf` vocẽ lê uma string, até o espaço, e coloca ela no arquivo. Mas os espaços são ignorados, isso é normal do `scanf`/`fscanf`. Se o seu objetivo é copiar de um arquivo para o outro, é melhor usar `fread`e `fwrite`.

Comment: O @C.E.Gesser tem razão. É melhor usar o `fgets`.

Answer (score 5):

De acordo com a documentação da função [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/):

> Whitespace character: the function will read and ignore any whitespace
>   characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character
>   (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters --
>   see isspace).

Traduzindo livremente:

"Caractere branco: a função irá ler e ignorar qualquer caractere branco encontrado antes do próximo caracter não branco (caracteres brancos incluem espaço, nova linha e tabulação)."

O que acontece então é que a sua leitura está sendo "quebrada" nos espaços do texto. Supondo o teste "Isto eh um teste.", a primeira leitura retornará simplesmente "Isto", e o resto será mantido no stream para retornar nas próximas leituras "eh", "um" e "teste." respectivamente.

Eu imaginei que você poderia incluir um espaço em branco entre cada leitura, mas o @C.E.Gesser bem lembrou que não há como saber se há um ou mais espaços entre as palavras. Assim, creio que o ideal é utilizar o [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) indicando o `stdin` como fonte para leitura e o tamanho máximo do buffer de dados:

```c
fgets(str, 100, stdin);
```

Comment: `fgets` é de fato a melhor alternativa. Colocar os espaços manualmente depois não vai funcionar, pois não tem como saber se era um ou mais espaços que havia entre as palavras.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser Verdade. Vou editar pra corrigir essa sugestão. :)

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que o `scanf("%s",str);` lê a string e ignora os espaços em branco. Uma solução para isso é `" %[^\n]"`, em vez de `%s`, que vai ler toda a linha escrita pelo usuário até encontrar um caractere `\n`, incluindo os espaços.

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", arquivo);
```

Ou

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", arquivo);
```

Esse segundo acrescenta um `%*c` para suprimir o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> que o usuário dará para confirmar o fim da string [(referência)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083045/scanf-n-skips-the-2nd-input-but-n-does-not-why).

---

No teste que fiz aqui com seu código, mudei também o `scanf("%d",&op);` para `scanf("%d%*c",&op);` pois o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> após digitar o índice, "engolia" a opções escolhida.

---

Obs: Considere utilizar a `fgets` em vez de `scanf`, se for possível. Ao se utilizar `scanf`, deve-se ficar atento a alguns detalhes para evitar *overflow* (conforme apresentado [aqui](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)).

Comment: Solução bacana! Mas acho que vale dar uma lida sobre as desvantagens do `scanf` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf). :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Interessante o link. Há bastante coisa a se considerar quando se vai utilizar `scanf`. De qualquer forma, é bom apresentar essa solução pois as vezes ele tem que usar `scanf` mesmo.